# Archivo .form desaparecido? Netbeans Java

Tags: netbeans, jframe

Tengo un proyecto donde en su momento generé una GUI con un form. El problema es que después de exportarlo el archivo .form ha desaparecido y no se encuentra en ningun lugar de mi ordenador. Sigo teniendo el código con todo el jframe y sus componentes, y si ejecuto el .java el proyecto sigue funcionando igualmente con todos sus componentes en su sitio y propiedades. Pero no puedo acceder a la pestaña diseño porque no existe ningun archivo .form. Alguna idea de que ha podido pasar o si puedo generar un JFrame a partir del código?

Comment: Yo he creado JFrames con el puro código. Solo crea una nueva clase JFrame en Netbeans y copia el código. Tendrás que cambiar el nombre de clase para que sea el mismo del código que tengas. Al momento de copiar el código se te debe generar todo lo demás.

Comment: @AlbertoLopez por desgracia no consigo que me coja los botones, texto etc... la pantalla de diseño se queda vacia pero si lo ejecuto si que sale bien, hay algo que me estoy perdiendo?

Comment: Te paso una liga de Netbeans que responde a tu pregunta. http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormGeneratingFormFile , sinceramente no recuerdo como le hice. Si puedo te aviso. Si usas Windows, esté hace respaldos periódicos, puedes buscar en esos respaldos para encontrar ese archivo que te falta.

Comment: @AlbertoLopez el form generator no esta respondiendo correctamente y en mis respaldos el ultimo respaldo esta hecho a dia de hoy, cuando ya no tenia el form. Porque el form generator me dice class not found

Comment: sinceramente tu problema se sale de mi conocimiento. En alguna ocasión tuve un problema con NetBeans que no encontré respuesta y me suscribí a su comunidad y puse mi duda y me respondieron y lo pude solucionar. Te paso la liga por si quieres intentar ahí https://netbeans.org/community/lists/index.html. Por otro lado no sé que versión tengas, pero quizás convenga hacer un update a la última versión y ver si se corrigen algunos problemas.

Comment: @AlbertoLopez no pasa nada, gracias por tu tiempo de todas formas

Comment: Suponiendo que se haya borrado, intenta usar algún software como recuva, no es normal que se borre tu `.form` y no es fácilmente replicable

Comment: Igual puedes reuperar los archivos borrados desde netbeans , pero creo que no es lo que buscas o sí?

Comment: @RuslanLópez no pude recuperarlos al final, tuve que hacer la interfaz gráfica a ciegas. por lo que costó más de lo que tocaba pero al final pude sacarlo, gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: Esperemos que algún día ayude a alguien :)